# Dynamically set the target model of an Eloquent Model relationship?

Tags: php, database, laravel, eloquent

I have a Laravel app that requires two separate tables for products. One model `PurchaseProduct` handles products that we will buy **from** our clients. Another model `SaleProduct` handles product that we will **sell** to our clients.

We are using a singular `Category` model to manage products. We have a pivot table `category_products` to manage the product/category relationships. It simply has `category_id` and `product_id` columns.

Because my app is an API, I want to receive a query parameter when a request is made to my endpoint. Like so: `/api/category&type=pp` `PP` will obviously translate into `PurchaseProduct` and `SP` to `SaleProduct`.

Okay, so what I am wanting to do is have a relationship declared on my `Category` model:

```
public function products()
{
    if ( -- ) {
        $model = 'App\Models\SaleProduct';
    } else {
        $model = 'App\Models\PurchaseProduct';
    }
    return $this->belongsToMany($model, 'category_products', 'category_id', 'product_id')->withTimestamps();
}
```

As you can see, I am unsure how to set this conditional statement to trigger the model I want to use for the relationship. If it were database based it wouldn't be that hard, but how could I somehow pass that query parameter to the model and dynamically set the correct product model?

Comment: Maybe this will work for you? https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relations

Answer (score 0):

The Model is usually not the right position do such logic, this should be done by the Controller.

In the Category Model just add two relations:

```
public function saleProducts()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\SaleProduct', 'category_products', 'category_id', 'product_id')->withTimestamps();
}

public function purchaseProducts()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\PurchaseProduct', 'category_products', 'category_id', 'product_id')->withTimestamps();
}
```

Now you can do something like this in your Controller:

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $categories = Category::where('id', $request->get('category_id'));

     switch ($request->get('type'))
     {
         case 'PP':
             $products = $categories->purchaseProducts()->get();
             break;
         case 'SP':
             $products = $categories->purchaseProducts()->get();
             break;
         default:
             throw new InvalidArgumentException('Wrong parameter');
     }

     return $products->toArray();
}
```

You have to adapt the principal to your exact needs.